# rails has_many through double?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bar

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :foo
has_many :baz

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :bar
```

I'm after all of Foo's bazs (Foo having many Baz because of Bar's relation). I'm thinking of just adding a `has_many :baz` to Foo, and a `belongs_to :foo` on Baz, but I feel like there's a relationship that I'm missing here.

Should I just use a scope? or is there a relation I can put on Foo to get all the baz?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just add a through.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  has_many :bazes, through: :bars
end
```

Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association for more information.

Comment: Your has_many's should be pluralized though `has_many bars` for example

Comment: your answer is correct just a note though the plural of `baz` is `bazs`. `"baz".pluralize #=> "bazs"`

Comment: same if i had some quxs that belonged to Baz? Could I then do `Foo has_many :quxs through: :bars`?

Comment: If it worked I think you'd have to do `has_many :quxs through: bazs`  I'm not sure how deep rails will allow you to nest it